# Variable in a table

Tags: php

Okay, so i got this code :

```
$serieid = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orderregels WHERE orderid='$headerdata["orderid"]'");
```

I want that variable $headerdata["orderid"] behind "WHERE orderid", How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this

```
$serieid = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orderregels WHERE orderid='{$headerdata['orderid']}'");
```

Or you can do this

```
$serieid = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orderregels WHERE orderid='" . $headerdata['orderid'] . "'");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$serieid = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orderregels WHERE orderid='".$headerdata["orderid"]."'");
```